# Using AddTarget for UIButton with MonoTouch and C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios

**EDIT: I now get the exception:**

```
 Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:43
  at MapKit01.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/andre/Downloads/MapKit03/MapKit03/Main.cs:20
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

0   MapKit01                            0x00091eac mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   MapKit01                            0x00005788 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9533f8cb _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x0274f258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
5   UIKit                               0x02810021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                               0x0281057f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
7   UIKit                               0x0280f6e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
8   UIKit                               0x0277ecef -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
9   UIKit                               0x0277ef02 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
10  UIKit                               0x0275cd4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
11  UIKit                               0x0274e698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
12  GraphicsServices                    0x04d40df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
13  GraphicsServices                    0x04d40ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
14  CoreFoundation                      0x012bfbf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
15  CoreFoundation                      0x012bf962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
16  CoreFoundation                      0x012f0bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
17  CoreFoundation                      0x012eff44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
18  CoreFoundation                      0x012efe1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
19  GraphicsServices                    0x04d3f7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
20  GraphicsServices                    0x04d3f668 GSEventRun + 104
21  UIKit                               0x0274bffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
22  ???                                 0x0e0c66ad 0x0 + 235693741
23  ???                                 0x0e0c61b0 0x0 + 235692464
24  ???                                 0x0e0c5f0c 0x0 + 235691788
25  ???                                 0x0e0c5ccc 0x0 + 235691212
26  ???                                 0x0e0c5eb6 0x0 + 235691702
27  MapKit01                            0x00009b52 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
28  MapKit01                            0x0016d02e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
29  MapKit01                            0x00171224 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
30  MapKit01                            0x00176615 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
31  MapKit01                            0x000671e5 mono_jit_exec + 149
32  MapKit01                            0x00204fd4 main + 1988
33  MapKit01                            0x00002b75 start + 53
34  ???                                 0x00000004 0x0 + 4

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

**Question**:
I like to use some code I found in Objective-C in my C# project.
It works fine at all but to use the line with addTarget let me think since a couple of hours with no working result.
So this is the original source for:

```
  UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And this is what I try with:

```
  UIButton infoButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
  infoButton.AddTarget(infoButton, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("showDetails"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

  public void showDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The result is not very nice the app crash without any response when I click the button ...

Can you help me please how to use it in C# the right way?

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 6):

Try using a C# event like this:

```
infoButton.TouchUpInside += showDetails;
```

Comment: You need to store the button in a class-level variable, instead of only having it in a method.

Comment: The reason for having to keep the button in a class level variable is that otherwise the Garbage Collector will destroy it, which is why you get the error.